# About the function "cvPOSIT" in OpenCV

Tags: c++, function, opencv

I want to calculate the pose of an object.Recently,I found that I can use "cvPOSIT" to finish my task from an assay.But I can't find this function in the OpenCV ducumentation.Is this function in use now?
Thank you for your answer!

Comment: `cvPOSIT` is obsolete (but still available in [C api](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2f4e38c8313ff313de7c41141d56d945d91f47cf/modules/calib3d/src/posit.cpp)). The new replacement is `solvePnP`. Have a look [here](https://github.com/pthom/TestSolvePnp) to find out how to use it